# Foto que vem da camera fica rotacionada

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <input 
        onChange={this.mostra} 
        type="file" 
        accept="image/jpeg" 
        name="img" 
        id="perfilfoto"/>
```

#### Função chamada quando escolho uma foto antes de enviar;

```
    mostra = ()=> {
    
            var doc = document.querySelector("#perfilfoto");
    
            let fread = new FileReader();
            fread.readAsDataURL(doc.files[0]);
    
            fread.onloadend = event => {
                this.setState({url: ""});
                this.setState({fat: event.target.result});
            }
        }
```

Quando busco a imagem da galeria que não seja da camera, podendo ser um print ou download, ela fica na posição normal, porém, se for da camera ou se for tirada no momento do envio, ela fica rotacionada... Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EXIF 'Orientation Flag'

```js
mostra = ()=> { 
let doc = document.querySelector("#perfilfoto")
let fread = new FileReader()

fread.onloadend = event => {
let photoExif = event.target.result

let dataURL =
`data:${ doc.files[0].type };base64,${ 
btoa( 
    photoExif.match(/Orientation>3/)? photoExif.replace(/Orientation>3/, 'Orientation>1')
  : photoExif.match(/Orientation>6/)? photoExif.replace(/Orientation>6/, 'Orientation>8')
  : photoExif
) }`;

this.setState({ url: '' })
this.setState({ fat: dataURL })
}

fread.readAsBinaryString( doc.files[0] )
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Continua não rotacionando... Qual poderia ser o problema? Quase não acho assuntos para esse tema... Faço isso no React e testo no meu celular pelo ip, é um galaxy s7, se é que isso pode ajudar

Comment: Wrong picture orientation on Samsung devices : https://github.com/google/cameraview/issues/22 ; How to automatically rotate an image based on exif data (on React): https://medium.com/@oscarfranco_14246/how-to-automatically-rotate-an-image-based-on-exif-data-on-react-a41a27feb57c